# Sorting array of Ints

Tags: go

I'm attempting to sort an array of Ints using the following function

```
func sortArray(array [100]int) [100]int {
    var sortedArray = array
    sort.Sort(sort.Ints(sortedArray))

    return sortedArray
}
```

and getting the following error:

> .\helloworld.go:22: cannot use sortedArray (type [100]int) as type []int in argument to sort.Ints
>   .\helloworld.go:22: sort.Ints(sortedArray) used as value

I'm trying to figure out Go and I'm getting stuck on this one.

Comment: `sort.Ints` (and indeed `sort.Sort`) expect a slice and you gave it an array.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can sort an array by taking a slice of the entire array

```
sort.Ints(array[:])
```

You probably don't want an array in the first place however, and should be using a slice of `[]int`.

Also, your `sortedArray` is the same value as `array`, so there is no reason to create the second variable.

Comment: Cheers, it worked. I'll read some more on slices to figure out the why. Thanks. I fixed my redundancy as well. Why does the second error message occur?

Comment: @Kaylined: The second error message is because you're trying to pass `sort.Ints` as an argument to `sort.Sort`. `sort.Ints` doesn't have a return value, and you don't need to call `sort.Sort`.

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't want an array in the first place however, and should be using a slice of []int.

Also, your sortedArray is the same value as array, so there is no reason to create the second variable.